# "I sightsaw London." Is this correct?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, compounds

Is the following phrase correct?

> I sightsaw London/the museum.

Comment: I must admit that I have never seen the simple past tense of "sightsee" used before. (And, admittedly, it gave me a bit of a chuckle.)  It's not obvious that it's wrong, but it's certainly not idiomatic.

Comment: I like it! Congratulations on minting this shiny new coin, or perhaps on noticing an old coin that no one else has seen long lying in a neglected corner.

Comment: This might be a better fit for ELL.

Comment: I like the combination of "sight" and "saw", but sadly there is (not yet) a verb of "to sightsaw" .. - "I sightsawed the city..." - this would sound so much like it actually had a meaning..

Comment: @Imago I think "sightsaw" isn't supposed to be the infinitive ("to sightsaw"), but rather the past tense of "to sightsee".

Comment: The formal form would be just plain "saw": "I saw the sights of London." or just "I saw the museum.". That being said, I can't argue "I sight-saw London." is unclear, even though it does sound funny.

Comment: [*sightsaw*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sightsaw%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&gws_rd=cr&ei=q__JVp3dE4q-aOSatrgJ) appears to have been used rarely, with many of the uses saying that the tensed forms *sightsaw*, *sightsees* and *sightseen* are not used.

Comment: Maybe *technically* grammatically correct, but to my ears it sounds like a joke, setting up for some kind of punchline.

Comment: "I went to London and saw the sights" is another possibility. Or "I went sightseeing in London".

Comment: See Oald  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sightsee?q=sightsee    Oald: only intransitive, only in progressive tense.

Comment: I think everyone will understand what you mean.  So go ahead and say you sightsaw London if you wish.

Answer (score 47):

Surprisingly, some dictionaries such as [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sightseeing) and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sightseeing) do list *sightsee* as a verb, with *sightsaw* as the past form.

On the other hand, I have never heard anybody actually say it. I have heard plenty of people say *went sightseeing*. A quick trip to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sightsaw%2C%20went%20sightseeing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20sightseeing%3B%2Cc0) to compare the usage of *sightsaw* against *went sightseeing* comes up with plenty of instances of *went sightseeing*, but *sightsaw* is 'not found'.

It appears that although some dictionaries are willing to list it as a verb, real live people don't actually use it as a verb.

Comment: To back you up, the dictionaries apparently do list sightsaw as the past of sightsee, but I've never heard anyone say it.  If you Google "sightsaw -definition -dictionary" (to eliminate such dictionary sites) you get very few hits, some of which are sellers of saws, and some are sentences where the two words appear back to back, unrelated to tourism ("An old man with second sight saw huge beasts...")

Comment: Your [ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sightsaw%2C+went+sightseeing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csightsaw%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20sightseeing%3B%2Cc0) link is wrong -- actually _sightsaw_ is found, just seldom

Comment: @MichaelChirico Most of them are linguistic books again, but there are some normal literature examples mixed in.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelChirico, the Ngram cited charts the two-word phrase **Sight saw** (capitalized) with "went sightseeing". Little wonder "Sight saw" is not found.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sightsaw%2Cwent+sightseeing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csightsaw%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20sightseeing%3B%2Cc0 *sightsaw* is "found", you have to reclick on the search box.

Answer (score 11):

It's debatable, and a lot of contributors are going to say no. MW says it is an intransitive verb and lists the past tense as "sightsaw". OALD on the other hand only mentions *sightseeing*, and that it is a noun. Depends on your dictionary I guess. It is not in common usage now, but language is always evolving, and what is *not in usage now* may very well be in 50 years.

Comment: MW online doesn’t mention transitivity at all (as far as I can tell, at least), so if your version of it says that _sightsee_ is an intransitive verb, then the sentence in the question would **not** be correct, because it’s used as a transitive verb there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sightsee Please check just below the headword. Also, do not rely on only one reference. The point we have been making is that the topic is debatable, depending on the dictionary.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Actually, you have made a very valid point, and I would like to throw it back out to the contributors. Tr. or Intr. ?

Comment: Well, now that is just utterly bizarre. That is precisely the page I looked at before, and I swear when I looked before, it only said “verb” (which I found rather odd: it usually does include transitivity). Anyway, my point—which was perhaps not very well-worded, but which this mysterious reappearance of the missing word on MW does support—was that the way it’s phrased in this answer, MW seems like it should support an affirmative answer; but since the example sentence is transitive and MW specifies intransitive, MW would be one of the nay-sayers.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ne pas avoir honte. or is ne vous inquiétez pas better? You are absolutely correct, which is why we are letting the wiser heads debate the point. Prof Ashworth is on point.

Answer (score 8):

Actually. it is. My first reaction was "Of course not, *sightsee* is intransitive", and that is certainly the only way I have ever heard it used. However, [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sightsee) implies that it is transitive, and the OED (subscription-only, so not linkable) has a secondary transitive meaning with respectable citations, including one from 1968, "I spent the day sight-seeing Berlin.", which seems an almost exact parallel.

So yes you can use the phrase, but I still wouldn't recommend it in a formal (or even non-journalese) context.

Comment: I was surprised to see that quite a few of OED's citations for both transitive and intransitive usage were *finite,* though you have not picked one of those. I was only really familiar with infinitive, present participle, and gerund usages, intransitive in all cases.

Comment: I'd put 'We spent the day sight-seeing Berlin.' // 'We sight-saw Berlin' // 'We sight-saw the museum' at 85% // 15% // 1% on the acceptability scale (the rarely encountered Marx-Unwin scale).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth for a total of 101%, if I may note.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: It doesn’t make sense to add up these numbers.

Comment: @chirlu I've tried to research this metric but found out empty. May I ask for a hint?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: I haven’t heard of Marx–Unwin either, but the general concept of acceptability is well-known ([Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality#Grammaticality_versus_acceptability)). If _The dog barked_ is 100% acceptable and _The cat meowed_ is 100% acceptable, too, that doesn’t mean that the sum being 200% is in any way a problem.

Comment: @chirlu: I think it means that the dog barking *and* the cat meowing simultaneously is just too much noise to tolerate ;-) For an analogy involving a different fractional scale, if four players on a baseball team each bat .300, it doesn't mean the team bats 1.200. It just doesn't make sense to add up unrelated percentages. However it's not entirely a coincidence that chirlu's numbers add up to *about* 100%, because 15%/85% are complementary guessed numbers meaning "not much" and "nearly all", so it's not all that surprising that those two add up to 100%.

Comment: Marx as in Groucho and Unwin as in Stanley: two expert language-manglers. True acceptability ratings require input from panels of linguists (and often fail to agree with each other). The percentages I suggest are subjective and unauthoritative (but I'm sticking to them).

Comment: @Edwin Two is a panel, right? I agree entirely with your percentages (and so do five others, though it’s hard to say how many of those are linguists), so I think we can promote them to at least a semi-true acceptability rating. :-)

Comment: @Janus I refuse to belong to any panel that will accept me as a member.

Answer (score 6):

## Short Answer

Use of the form *sightsaw*, while grammatically consistent, is nevertheless nonstandard and awkward.  Furthermore, if used as a verb, *to sightsee* is intransitive, so the formulation "sightsaw London" would be incorrect; "sightsaw in London" should be used instead.

## Explanation

The reason why it seems awkward to place *to sightsee* in the past tense, more so than other verbs, is that the word was not coined as a verb.  Rather, it was first coined as a noun, to describe the activity of *sightseeing*, with a *sightseer* being one who sees sights.  And because of its historical use as a noun, repurposing the word as a verb is novel, and therefore comes across as nonstandard and even awkward.

For this reason, I would recommend caution using *to sightsee* as a verb in writing, the same as any other nonstandard grammatical construction.  The prerogative is yours as a writer, but you should be aware that the usage is nonstandard and will come across that way to your readers.

Now, regarding transitivity, I assert that *to sightsee*, if used as a verb, **must** be intransitive (despite dictionary opinions to the contrary), the reason being that the original verb *to see* is transitive in this construction and already has an object, "sights".  Since *to see* has already discharged its transitivity in the object "sights", the full construction *to sightsee* cannot anticipate another object, and must therefore be intransitive.

To apply this to the proposed clause "I sightsaw London", "London" cannot be the object of the verb *sightsaw* because *to see* has already been satisfied with an object, "sights".  The correct formulation of the clause must be "I sightsaw in London", equivalent to "I saw the sights in London".

It may be instructive to compare with other similar constructions in English, such as *faultfinding* and *whale watching*, both coined as nouns describing activities.

Comment: Incidentally, my 1977 Merriam-Webster does list _sightsee_ as an intransitive verb with etymology "back-formation from _sightseeing_."

Answer (score 5):

Supplementing the answers that have been posted, I feel that some clarification is in order.

The expression *sightseeing* is normally fixed, it is often preceded by the verbs *do*, *be* or *go*.

> **Q**: What are you doing tomorrow?
>
> **A**: I'**m** sightseeing
>   **A**: I'll **be** sightseeing
>   **A**: I'm **doing** some sightseeing
>   **A**: I'm **going** sightseeing
>   **A**: I'm going to **go** sightseeing

The structure of  ***go sightseeing*** is no different from say: *go swimming*, *go dancing*, or *go fishing*, but whereas *swimming*, *dancing* and *fishing* are also verbs, the expression *sightseeing* is different, it is more like a noun. You do not normally conjugate *sightsee*

- He sightsees when he's on holiday/in vacation. (RARE)
- We want to sightsee in New York. (RARE)
- They should sightsee, it's a wonderful city. (RARE)
- Yesterday, I sightsaw (in) Paris (VERY RARE)

Instead the following is more idiomatic in English

- He **goes** sightseeing when he's on holiday/in vacation.
- We want **to go** sightseeing in New York.
- They should **go** sightseeing, it's a wonderful city.
- Yesterday, I **went** sightseeing in Paris
- Yesterday, I [**did** some sightseeing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sightseeing) in Paris

However, *sightsee* is often conjugated in the past continuous tense, and this structure feels very natural and idiomatic to me.

- While I **was sightseeing** in Rome
- ... you were sightseeing
- ... she/he was sightseeing 
  (etc.)

Lastly, you do not normally go sightseeing *in* a museum. The verbs  *visit* and *see* are usually preferred in English.

> **Q**: What did you do yesterday?
>
> **1**. I *visited* the British Museum
>   **2**. I *saw* the British Museum
>   **3**. I *went sightseeing* in the British Museum. (RARE)
>   **4**. I *sightsaw* the British Museum (INCORRECT)

EDIT

To understand how rare  *sightsaw* (blue line) is, compared to *went sightseeing* (red line) see the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sightsaw%2Cwent%20sightseeing&year_start=1920&year_end=2007&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csightsaw%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20sightseeing%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csightsaw%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20sightseeing%3B%2Cc1) chart below

[image]

Although *sightsaw* has been used very rarely by native speakers, at least in its written form, we cannot dismiss it as being non-existent. Even distinguished British and American authors didn't flinch at using it in their informal correspondence.

The following is an excerpt from the [*Diaries of James Lees-Milne*](https://books.google.it/books?id=3fIEHXDK5toC&pg=PT217&dq=%22sightsaw%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz1dLfg5PLAhXFew4KHdKTDcwQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=%22sightsaw%22&f=false)  written between 1942 and 1954

> It was their first time on the Continent, and **they sightsaw for a week in Paris**—daytripping to Versailles, where they visited the Grand Trianon and the Palais. The rest of September, they visited Switzerland and Italy's lakes before sailing home ...

The American writer Allen Ginsberg used the noun as if it were a proper verb in a [letter](https://books.google.it/books?id=7jEwBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT410&dq=%22sightsaw%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj61fTsg5PLAhVE_w4KHYvCDjE4ChDoAQg3MAU#v=onepage&q=%22sightsaw%22&f=false) addressed to Robert Creeley in 1967

> …then we went on to Paris and sat on Pont des Arts and looked at the summer trees along the seine and sat in cafes and **sightsaw**, I got hotels and taxis and carried luggage…

Comment: So, I should use the verb "sightsee" only in progressive tenses just like OALD site points out: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sightsee?q=sightsee . Could you tell if "I was sightseeing in London." means the same as "I was visiting London". ?

Comment: @masterkomp if you're referring to its grammar, and not strictly to its meaning, then "I was visiting..." and "I was sightseeing..." are both used in the same way, to express an action that was in progress at a specific period in the past.

Comment: I mean the meaning. What's the difference?

Comment: @masterkomp well they're not always interchangeable, for instance I can visit a country, a park, a castle, or a friend. In none of them do I go sightseeing. I could visit London without seeing the typical sights that a tourist may want to see and take photos of. I might be interested in seeing a museum or an art gallery, would I say "I went sightseeing" when I came back home? No, not really. Sightseeing in London means going to places that are world-famous  tourist attractions such as; Big Ben, Buckingham Place, The London Tower, Oxford St., Piccadilly Circus, the London Eye etc..

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers point out *to sightsee sth.* as a full-fledged transitive verb is very rare if not generally unacceptable. To me, "sight-seeing" is visiting famous places, doing "touristy" things. For one place only, I would use **visit** (or **saw**):

> I visited the museum.
>   I saw Big Ben.

For London, it might be better to paraphrase as

> I went sight-seeing in London.
>   I did some sight-seeing in London.
>   I spent the day/week-end sight-seeing London.

Comment: "I saw the Big Ben" Proper nouns rarely take articles, and the ones that do are usually phrases that would have meaning as improper nouns (e.g., "the United States"). You saw Big Ben.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have never been to London, but I did search for this before I posted. "saw the Big Ben" seems to be a lot more common than "saw Big Ben" but if you're certain I shall take your word for it.

Comment: That's strange. I wonder if most of the hits were from non-native speakers?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Lots of non-native speakers posting in English about visiting Big Ben... Maybe! If you look at results from UK-based websites, "Big Ben" without the article seems to be the norm. I don't know if the other results are mainly from non-native speakers or non-British native speakers (and I don't care enough to read a representative number of results).

Comment: Reminds me of this George W Bush quote: "And one of the things that I use on the Google is to pull up maps [...]" BTW I live in London and have often seen Big Ben.

Answer (score 4):

A better usage is, "I *saw sights* in London."

Even though "sightseeing" is the noun, the verb form is not "sight see." It is more like "see sights."

Comment: Shouldn't it be, "I saw the sights of [London/the museum]?"

Comment: @Elian: That is ok also.

Comment: How about, "I took in the sights of [London/the museum]?"

Comment: @Elian: "Six of one, half a dozen of the other."

Comment: I've often seen sights when I wasn't sightseeing.

Answer (score 1):

Your other answers are right in the general case.  But  you could get away with it in the right register -- not a formal one.  I suggest that *to go sightseeing* somewhere is to see some/most of the sights, while *to sightsee* -- transitive -- somewhere is to see all the sights.  So "I sightsaw London until there were no more sights to see"/"I sightsaw the hell out of London" would be non-conventional but easily understood forms for seeing all the sights.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Regardless of a couple of dictionaries, the past tense of 'sightsee' does not see use, and 'sightsee' itself does not see use except in extremely rare circumstances.

The common use is 'sightseeing' as in 'I went sightseeing in [town, city, or area]', or 'saw', as in 'I saw the [more specific landmark or very specific location]'.  Also as a response to 'where did you go' 'sightseeing in [town, city, or area]' or 'what did you do?' 'sightseeing in [town, city, or area]'.  Sometimes tours will be advertised as 'sightseeing tours', or just 'sightseeing'.

I have never seen or come across 'sightsaw' and google backs up that that phrase/word does not see use whatsoever even amongst poor english speakers.

Comment: I'm old-fashioned enough to believe it should be `sight-seeing`. As for usage, is your analysis about poverty-stricken Englishmen, Anglophones with little liquidity or those with a poor command of English?

Comment: @Magoo - the modern usage is sightseeing.  Sight-seeing is archaic at this point.  Poor english speaker is likewise a well known term for someone who is poor at speaking english - it's usage to describe english-speakers who are below the poverty line would be at best in the context of a multiple-language region with language/cultural discrimination.  'English speaker' no longer, if it ever did, describes solely residents of the UK.